# Upload optimized images to magento cloud server

Tags: magento2, cloud

We have 90 optimized images that we need to upload to our production server hosted in Magento Cloud, the problem is that Magento Cloud just provides read-access only, is there a proper fast way to do this process without having to upload the images one by one on the admin?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your magento directory on your local machine.

```
magento-cloud environment:checkout yourmaster-branch
```

copy/swap your images to proper directory

```
magento-cloud redeploy -e yourmaster-branch
```