# Magento2 Cloud - Add Images through API

Tags: magento2-cloud

When attempting to add images programmatically to a Magento cloud instance we are getting the following error:

**Warning: mkdir(): Read-only file system**

We did find the following post, but the reply says we need to checkout the instance using GIT, copy the files locally and then redeploy. There must be a better way?

[Upload optimized images to magento cloud server](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269253/upload-optimized-images-to-magento-cloud-server)

Answer (score 0):

The media directory is not read-only. If you are having problems check your `.magento.app.yaml` file and ensure the following section is present:

```
mounts:
    "var": "shared:files/var"
    "app/etc": "shared:files/etc"
    "pub/media": "shared:files/media"
    "pub/static": "shared:files/static"
```

I would also check where the `Warning: mkdir(): Read-only file system` error is coming from and check its not trying to create a directory where it shouldn't.